# How can a section of a website stay displayed (kind of like loaded only once) when navigating the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website with multiple pages on it. All of the pages have the same exact top section, navigation bar and footer. The only thing that changes when navigating to a different page is the body. What I want to know is how to load only the body of the page when navigating to the different pages but keep the top, nav bar and footer displayed so that the effect you'd get is that nothing changes except the body.

Comment: Users like to be able to share/bookmark content.  Most implementations of what you describe take away the ability to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old-school answer to this is to use [frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html). Frames do exactly what you want; you have a page wherein you specify separate HTML files for the top, bottom, and main panes of your site. Navigating around just loads different pages into the "main" frame. However, this isn't really done anymore, for various reasons: it's clunky looking, has odd scroll behavior, and is annoying when linking to and from other sites.

A better way to do it might be load the main content via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). You would show a page with just the header and footer, and then use Javascript to dynamically pull the right page off of the server and insert its content into a placeholder div in the page. Navigating to other pages involves running JS code to load that the linked-content and replace everything in the placeholder. This too has disadvantages: you need to add special handling for history (i.e. making the back button work as expected) and deep linking (e.g. making bookmarks load the right content).

I recommend doing neither of those. Much better is to just have the header and footer content in all of the pages. There are a few ways to do that without repeating the HTML code in a bunch of places: if you're generating the pages dynamically, look at *layouts*, which allow you to specify a reusable template for all the pages. The exact method would depend on the framework you're using, but as an example, here's [how you do it in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). If your pages are static (i.e. some HTML files you upload to a server), you'll want to do something similar, but instead of generating the pages on-the-fly, you'd use a static HTML generator and compile your pages. That allows you to specify a header and footer in one place and then your content in separate files. After you edit them, you run a command and it creates output files with a copy of the header and footer in each. Then you upload them. See, for example, [Jekyll](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/lessons/jekyll-introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks to everyone that answered. I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to everything beyond HTML and CSS so I didn't even know how to look for what I was trying to do. This is certainly more than enough to get me going, so thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices:

- [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) - Where the body  of the page is an `iframe` element and you change the iframe `src` to load the new pages
- [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) - Where JavaScript uses an XMLHttpRequest to fetch the HTML of the new page and loads it dynamically into the body without re-loading the page

Comment: Also, the iframe method can work without *any* JavaScript, by giving links a `target` attribute that is equal to the iframe's `name` attribute (i.e. `<iframe name="blah"></iframe><a href=".." target="blah" />`)

Answer (score 0):

I was contemplating this myself for another reason but what I was thinking is that you can attach a javascript event handler to all the anchor tags with 'href' attribute.  On firing these events it would call an XHR(pure js) or $.get(jquery) to the target, dump out the contents of the div containing the body that is dynamic and swap in the new stuff.

You'd have to consider that you need to move your form submissions to an XHR method as well.

One example that's already in use is www.facebook.com.  When you click around the page refreshes as normal.  When you open the chat and start talking the page starts reloading through some kind of Ajax method.